# How to substitute text in vimscript?

Tags: vimscript

I want to replace b by a in visual selection.

I have vimscript like this:

```
execute("normal! vip:s/a/b/g")
```

It works in command line mode. But not work in vimscript.

How to fix it?

How to replace the text directly on original text in vimscript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do:

```
execute 'normal! vip' | s/a/b/g
```

Comment: Doesn't escape out of the visual mode. (Which may be desired by OP, I dunno.)

Comment: execute `'normal! vip' | '<, '>s/a/b/g`` is correct thank you

Comment: @lizhe Accept the answer if you find it helpful, though I'd recommend you to check the other answer as well in case that may be more efficient.

Comment: @lizhe Accept the answer if you find it helpful, though I'd recommend you to check the other answer as well in case that may be more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

I would probably write

```
'{,'}substitute/a/b/g
```

in a function.

Comment: `'{,'}substitute/a/b/g` is correct in my vim. `+` or `-` will lost first and last line. Thank you

Comment: @lizhe hm, for some reason I was thinking they were the same as the `{}` motions, which usually hit the blank line. Will adjust.

Comment: Hi do you know why    execute("normal! vip") " work"
    '<,'>s/$/,/g "work"
    execute("'<,'>s/$/,/g") " not work

Comment: @lizhe generally I’d advise against `:execute` or `execute()` (which are quite different) unless you need them, and this case I don’t think you do. I think the one in your OP is missing an `\<enter>` press after `:s/a/b/g` since it’s being run through `normal!`. The one in your comments I would expect to work.